# If a percent difference is (approximately) normally distributed, can I calculate the confidence interval of its mean with a t distribution?

Tags: confidence-interval

I have measured the same variable at two time points. The variable is approximately normally distributed (this approximation is supported for the measures at both time points), and I have calculated the percent change between them.

I am unsure about how to obtain a confidence interval for the mean of the percent change. If the percent difference was approximately normally distributed, would it be possible to calculate the confidence interval using the t distribution?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to look at percent changes, you assume that any effect is multiplicative instead of additive, which means that the expected change is larger if the initial value is large. Is this scientifically plausible?

If so, work on the log-scale. An additive effect on the log-scale automatically becomes a multiplicative effect on the original scale, and it is straightforward to backtransform your confidence interval for the effect on log-scale.